# Get first row of join

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have a linq query that joins two tables (no relation in the actual db)

the relation is:
Companies 1 - n Phones

```
var miniCompanies =
    (from companies in db.Companies 
     join phones in db.Phones on companies.Id equals phones.CompanyId
     select new
     {
         companies.Name,
         phones.Phone,
     }).ToList().Distinct();
```

this returns something like:

```
----------------------------
company1     |    12345    |
----------------------------
company1     |    23456    |
----------------------------
company2     |    43242    |
----------------------------
company2     |    34234    |
----------------------------
company2     |    65442    |
----------------------------
```

i need to get only the fisrt in Phones table not everything
how to do that?
Edit:maybe i wasn't clear about what want sorry for that.
i ment:
    ----------------------------
    company1     |    12345    |
    ----------------------------
    company2     |    43242    |
    ----------------------------

i want the first phone for each company

Comment: If you had a relationship in your DBML, you could just do this: `var miniCompanies = db.Companies.Select(c => new { c.Name, c.Phones.First().Phone});`

Comment: That's not really the first phone for company2. I assume you mean any phone.

Comment: no that was a typing mistake, i will fix it

Comment: First has no meaning without an order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GroupBy:

```
var miniCompanies =
(from companies in db.Companies 
 join phones in db.Phones on companies.Id equals phones.CompanyId
 select new
 {
     companies.Name,
     phones.Phone,
 }).GroupBy(c=>c.Name).Select(c=>c.FirstOrDefault()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

1 You can try with `First operator`

```
(from companies in db.Companies 
 join phones in db.Phones on companies.Id equals phones.CompanyId
 select new
 {
     phones.Phone,
 }).First();
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/system.linq.queryable.first.aspx

2 You can also use `FirstOrDefault`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/system.linq.queryable.firstordefault.aspx

3 You can also use `Take(1);`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/bb300906.aspx

Comment: The ToList() and Distinct() seem a little wasteful.

Comment: This only returns the first company and phone, not the first phone for each company

Answer (score -2):

I would use the following:

```
var miniCompanies =
(from companies in db.Companies 
 join phones in db.Phones on companies.Id equals phones.CompanyId
 select new
 {
     companies.Name,
     phones.Phone,
 }).ToList().Distinct().FirstOrDefault();
```

The 'FirstOrDefault()' method will return the first item in the collection. If the collection contains no elements, the default object will be returned. For nullable types, this will be  a 'null' object. This is a good way to prevent your application from failing due to an exception related to an empty collection.

Comment: This only returns the first company and phone, not the first phone for each company